# Adding transparent overlay on google map

Tags: google-maps

I was looking at apartment listings when I came across this,

[image]

And I am wondering how it is achieved?

EDIT:

Found the image overlay using inspect element. 
Question is, is there an api to do things like this?

Comment: Why don't you take a look at the code?

Comment: I did. I found the image when I did an inspect element. looks like its a simple overlay. Now I am wondering if there is an api to do things like this.

Comment: maybe the overlay image is a transparent png? link to page?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a custom map type with the help of the [ImageMapType](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#ImageMapType) object. 
You can implement it to returned a darkened/half-transparent images for the map tiles. You can then overlay this map type over the normal one [like so](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#ImageMapTypes).

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be no.  There's no API for adding fixed images over a google map.  Why?  Because it's the standard behavior for any div (if you want to mimic what they did, just put a div after the map div and position it absolutely...in this case top:0 and left:0 with 100% width and a gradient or static image as a background).  You can place any div over any other div, even if it contains a google map.  Now there are api's for placing items INSIDE the map...these drawings can be just about anything, but they require a lat/long boundary because they are inside the map.  There are also map controls you can place on the map....similar to a fixed div, BUT it has a certain flow inside the map, so if you have a map terrain dropdown and you click it, if that dropdown overlaps another map control, that map control will move down.